# Need custom recovery that supports Kit Kat for Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7"

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I really want to flash CyanogenMod 11 on my tablet. I have the file in CM Updater, but I can't find a custom recovery that will support KitKat for my device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the latest CWM or TWRP custom recovery with your device.

Source: [Install Android 4.4 KitKat on Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 Using CM11 Custom Build](http://androidcentral.us/2013/11/how-to-install-android-4-4-kitkat-galaxy-tab-2-7-0-using-cm11-tutorial/)

**UPDATE #1:** XDA has a thread for [custom recoveries for the P3110](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2518232). It says that only CWM supports KitKat for that tablet.

Comment: No there is no official recovery for my tablet the supports kit kat it says error status 7

Comment: @user51878 I'm not sure I understand you. You're supposed to flash a custom recovery (CWM / TWRP), not a stock (which I assume you meant by official) recovery. Go to the TWRP site, and download the recovery there for your phone, and flash it. I assume your phone is rooted; is it?

Comment: Yes my phone is rooted in on cm 10.1 and I have Cwm and access to Twrp. BUT the newest version on the custom recovery site is still outdated and won't support cm 11. So I need any recovery that will in order to flash kit kat cm 11

Comment: @user51878 See my UPDATE#1 in the answer